# In Google Dialogflow CX, how do I make sure that links are opened in a new tab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, widget, dialogflow-cx

I have integrated a Dialogflow CX chatbot on my website using the Dialogflow Messenger UI. Now I want to make sure that if a user clicks on a link within the messenger widget, this link is opened in a new tab and not within the widget. How can I set this up? Thanks for your input!

I tried adding JavaScript code to the site my chatbot is deployed on, but the Code doesnt seem to have any effect on how links are behaving.